Есть ли существенная разница между перечислением аргументов и ключевым args
Метод передачи параметров с помощью keyword *args или **kwargs.
В качестве примера реализации этих ключевых слов был реализован класс Car:
class Car():
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.speed = args[0]
        self.color = args[1]

audi = Car(200, 'red')
bmw = Car(250, 'black')
mb = Car(190, 'white')

print(audi.color)
print(bmw.speed)

Как мы видим, при создании объекта класса Car, были переданы параметры в метод __init__ и после присваивание значений из массива args.
Вопрос:
Если мы используем вместо args обычное перечисление аргументов, будет ли существенная разница или ничего не произойдет?
UPD: Исходя из ответов и комментарий я подумал об удачных примерах использования этих keywords. В основном, была бы удобна передача всех аргументов в одну кучу и последующей записи или обработки. Например:
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',
                    level=logging.INFO)

def logger(func):
    def log_func(*args):
        logging.info(f'Running "{func.__name__}" with arguments {args}')
        print(func(*args))

    return log_func

def add(x, y):
    return x+y

def sub(x, y):
    return x-y

add_logger = logger(add)
sub_logger = logger(sub)

add_logger(3, 3)
add_logger(4, 5)

sub_logger(10, 5)
sub_logger(20, 10)

Получаем результат:
python .\ClosureFuntcionsPython.py
6
9
5
10

cat .\example.log
INFO:root:Running "add" with arguments (3, 3)
INFO:root:Running "add" with arguments (4, 5)
INFO:root:Running "sub" with arguments (10, 5)
INFO:root:Running "sub" with arguments (20, 10)


Существенная разница - смысловая. По "заголовку" функции нельзя будет понять, какие аргументы у нее есть, сколько их, их типы и т.д. Обязательно "произойдет" - вы забудете какие там аргументы есть вообще, или перепутаете их порядок, или еще что-то.

Поздравляю, вы изобрели декораторы.

Визуальные отличия
Давайте посмотрим, что будет, если мы не передадим ожидаемые аргументы в класс.
audi = Car()

В вашем классе будет вызвано исключение IndexError, что сделает запутанным работу с классом, при работе с классом вам придётся каждый раз вспоминать, что ожидает увидеть на входе класс, или читать код этого класса. И тот, и другой варианты кажутся не практичными.

IndexError: tuple index out of range

А, использовав позиционные аргументы в классе, если забыть указать speed и color будет вызвано исключение TypeError и будет понятно, что было не так сделано.
class Car():
    def __init__(self, speed, color):
        self.speed = speed
        self.color = color


TypeError: Car.__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments:
'speed' and 'color'

Кроме того, как удачно подметил insolor, невозможно заранее узнать, какие аргументы нужно будет передать классу, что недопускает возможности использовать типизацию. Это сделает код нечитабельным и непригодным для дальнейшей поддержки как для самого автора, так и какого-нибудь контрибьютора.
По ту сторону байт-кода
Давайте же посмотрим, какие инструкции выполняются в обоих классах

Рассмотрим первый класс, в котором мы получаем скорость и цвет из args

import dis

class Car:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.speed = args[0]
        self.color = args[1]

dis.dis(Car)

Результат:
Disassembly of __init__:
  5           0 RESUME                   0

  6           2 LOAD_FAST                1 (args)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              6 BINARY_SUBSCR
             10 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
             12 STORE_ATTR               0 (speed)

  7          22 LOAD_FAST                1 (args)
             24 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             26 BINARY_SUBSCR
             30 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
             32 STORE_ATTR               1 (color)
             42 RETURN_CONST             0 (None)

На первый взгляд, ничего интересного. Но давайте внимательно посмотрим на то, как мы достаём нужные нам аргументы.
Мы загружаем args, загружаем константу (индекс), затем через инструкцию BINARY_SUBSCR мы ищем в кортеже нужный аргумент, такая инструкция имеет свой метод __getitem__, полученный результат присваиваем атрибуту self.speed и тоже самое для self.color.

А как это будет выглядеть в классе с позиционными аргументами?

import dis

class Car:
    def __init__(self, speed, color):
        self.speed = speed
        self.color = color

dis.dis(Car)

Смотрим:
Disassembly of __init__:
 11           0 RESUME                   0

 12           2 LOAD_FAST                1 (speed)
              4 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              6 STORE_ATTR               0 (speed)

 13          16 LOAD_FAST                2 (color)
             18 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
             20 STORE_ATTR               1 (color)
             30 RETURN_CONST             0 (None)

Здесь мы напрямую загружаем значения в наши атрибуты.
Это означает, что класс с неименованными аргументами будет выполнять на несколько инструкций больше.
Гипотеза: класс с неименованными аргументами будет медленнее, чем класс с позиционнными аргументами
Производительность
Естественно, тесты слишком синтетические и результаты этих тестов будут очень далеки от реальности, но для показательного сравнения подойдут.
Замеры будем проводить с помощью timeit:
import timeit

class Car:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.speed = args[0]
        self.color = args[1]


class Car1:
    def __init__(self, speed, color):
        self.speed = speed
        self.color = color


def test_car():
    Car(200, "red")

def test_car1():
    Car1(200, "red")

timeit.timeit(test_car), timeit.timeit(test_car1)

Для класса с неименованными аргументами получили 0.13930917900142958 попугаев, а для класса с позиционными аргументами - 0.1009512620003079 попугаев.
Это означает, что гипотеза верна. Однако эта разница настолько микроскопическая в данном контексте, что её можно даже не учитывать. Но другой вопрос, когда у нас в классе будет использоваться в разы больше аргументов.

В каких моментах разработки мы можем полагаться на эти keywords?

Так называемые args можно использовать, когда аргументы должны быть позиционными и неограниченными по количеству. Например, какой-нибудь перебор чисел. А kwargs позволяет указывать неограниченное количество именованных аргументов.
Я бы сказал, что всё зависит от конкретного сценария, в котором вы собираетесь применять kwargs или args.

@gwgw в довольно узких случаях. Например, в функции print параметры через *args принимаются. Имена для них не важны, просто нужно принять набор строк и вывести их на экран. Или функция/класс dict - параметры принимаются через **kwargs, какие конкретно имена и значения - не важно, примет любые, имена параметров станут ключами в словаре, значения - значениями по этим ключам.

@gwgw ну и по терминологии из *args и **kwargs только kwags можно назвать "keywords" (буквально keyword arguments), args - это никакие не keywords. Сами слова args и kwargs не являются зарезервировнными ключевыми словами, вместо них может быть что угодно, хоть *foo и **bar
